# Passar valores via Ajax para Controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net

Quero passar valores via ajax de um campo texto na minha tela para minha action, estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
$('#Regra').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val().trim != '') {
            var regra = $('#Regra').val();
            var tipoAtribuicao = $('#TipoAtribuicao').val();
            $.fiajax({
                url: urlTipoAtribuicao,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { regra: regra, tipoAtribuicao: tipoAtribuicao },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status && data.status == 'OK') {
                        console.log('entrou');
                        $('#DescricaoRegra').val(data.record.Descricao);
                    } else {
                        console.log('entrou no else');
                        if (data.error && data.error.Message)
                            alert(data.error.Message);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
            });
```

Quero passar o campo Regra e o campo TipoAtribuicao, porem está dando erro 500, estou fazendo algo de errado ?

Comment: Que tipo de elemento é `#TipoAtribuicao`? É um input, um select...? E por que vc está usando `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`? Erro `500` é erro de servidor. Onde está dando esse erro? No alert?

Answer (score 0):

Cara aparentemente o seu código está correto. Dá uma olhada no action representado em seu 'urlTipoAtribuicao'. Veja oque ele espera receber como parâmetros e os tipos desses parâmetros. Veja se os campos var regra = $('#Regra').val() e var tipoAtribuicao = $('#TipoAtribuicao').val(); estão recebendo e passando os valores corretos. Vale a pena colocar um break point no seu metodo e debugar para ver aonde ele vai 'chorar'.

Comment: Então, até cai na controller, porem o primeiro parametro vem valor, o 2 vem null mesmo preenchendo o campo.

Comment: No caso o segundo atributo seria o var tipoAtribuicao = $('#TipoAtribuicao').val() correto?
dá uma olhada se TipoAtribuicao é mesmo um id ou uma classe. Pois nesse caso mudaria de $('#TipoAtribuicao').val() para $('.TipoAtribuicao').val()
Ou se em algum momento esse campo com o id TipoAtribuicao está se repetindo na sua página e ele está pegando o valor do último. Acontece muito com campos radio ou checkbox.
O problema é que são muitos cenários para avaliar, mas esses 2 são os mais comuns.

Comment: Resolvido, era o nome do parametro na controller no c# nao sabia que tinha que ser o mesmo nome passado no JS, pensei que só o tipo bastasse kkkkk falta de atenção valeu.